# Connecting to local SQL Server database in visual studio for mac

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've just started using Visual Studio for mac and I'm testing out an MVC project. I've downloaded the SQL Server docker image and created a database inside the container. I'm just not sure how to connect to this database in Visual Studio for mac. Am I even going about this right or is there a better way to create databases from within Visual Studio for mac?

Comment: Are you using Kitematic for launch the docker image or are you using docker CLI? also please post your run statement

Comment: Using docker CLI. By run statement do you mean the docker run statement? If so, it's:  `docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<password>' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Developer' --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -p 1401:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
<containerid>`

Comment: There will be a Startup.cs file which has the connection details ? If so update that with the connection details and run `dotnet restore` in the terminal within the IDE and then `dotnet run`

Comment: Sometimes the connection is configure through app settings as well. In that case you will see a entry in `appsettings.json`

Answer (score 2):

you need to Connect from outside the container.

have a look on this article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker

Connect from outside the container
You can also connect to the SQL Server instance on your Docker machine from any external Linux, Windows, or macOS tool that supports SQL connections.

The following steps use sqlcmd outside of your container to connect to SQL Server running in the container. These steps assume that you already have the SQL Server command-line tools installed outside of your container. The same principals apply when using other tools, but the process of connecting is unique to each tool.

Find the IP address for the machine that hosts your container. On Linux, use ifconfig or ip addr. On Windows, use ipconfig.

Run sqlcmd specifying the IP address and the port mapped to port 1433 in your container. In this example, that is port 1401 on the host machine.

bash

Copy
sqlcmd -S 10.3.2.4,1401 -U SA -P ''
PowerShell

Copy
sqlcmd -S 10.3.2.4,1401 -U SA -P ""
Run Transact-SQL commands. When finished, type QUIT.

Other common tools to connect to SQL Server include:

Comment: The common tools list seems to be missing. But good answer so far :-)